# Fatal error when extending abstract class in PHP

Tags: php, abstract-class

I'm learning advanced level of OOP PHP..(Or I want to learn :))

[This](http://pastebin.com/2L97YmLG) is my code.

Excerpt:

```
<?php 
abstract class Karakter
{
    abstract public function isim($name);
    abstract public function yas($age);

    public function yazdir()
    {
        print $this->isim() . " " . $this->yas();
    }
}

class Insan extends Karakter
{
    public $isim;
    public $yas;
    public function isim()
    {
        return "Bu adamın ismi: " . $this->isim;
    }

    public function yas()
    {
        return "Bu adamın yaşı: " . $this->yas;
    }
}
```

When I run this code I can't win through. I can see this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Insan::isim() must be compatible with that of Karakter::isim() in C:\AppServ\www\OOP\1.php on line 26
```

Comment: Your code link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please include the relevant code inside your question, not linked.

Comment: @Bryan stackoverflow does not allow.. because my code very long..

Comment: @YusufAliBozkır For the future, it would be good to try and narrow your code down as much as possible to the relevant parts so they fit in the question and let people know what code is specifically a problem. :)

Comment: Personally, I would have used [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) instead of Pastebin for the complete file, but putting relevant bits of code in the post is a *Good Idea*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined the function `isim` in the abstract class with one parameter.

```
abstract public function isim($name);
```

In order to correctly implement this function in any subclass you must override the function with exactly one parameter:

```
class Insan extends Karakter {
    public function isim($name) {
       [..]
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your abstract class, you defined `isim()` to expect a parameter. But in the extending class, you did not follow this rule.

This is the definition:

```
abstract public function isim($name);
```

But then you extend it like this, without a parameter:

```
public function isim()
```